# Escape Characters That Do Not Move Cursor

Tags: python, escaping

I have a function that prints out text one character at a time. The function waits .01 seconds before printing out the next character, which give it a nice flowing feel to it. I also have it pause slightly longer for characters such as periods, commas, basically anything that would cause a break in speech if the sentence were being spoken out loud.

I am trying to write an intro to my game, and I would like it to pause for 5 seconds at the end of each paragraph. My first thought was to use '\n', but that turned out disastrous due to some formatting issues (any time enter was used in the block of text it would wait 5 seconds). I tried using '\r' and '\v', but I didn't like how it moved the cursor (either at the beginning of the line, or in the middle of nowhere).

I was wondering if there was an escape character that I could use that didn't move the cursor, and also didn't print anything? If not, could I make my own?

Here is the code used for printing the text:

```
def slowText(text, length):
    for c in text:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()

        if c == '.' or c == '!' or c == '?' or c == ';' or c == ':':
            time.sleep(.5)
        elif c == ',':
            time.sleep(.2)
        elif c == '\r':
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            time.sleep(length)
    print "\n"
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where do you get the printout? (Python does not allow idle, you must try Shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any character that you would like to serve this purpose; the catch is simply to not print that character to the screen, since you are only using it to divide paragraphs. You would want to reorganize your code to look something like this:

```py
PAR_SEP = '\r'

def slowText(text, length):
    for c in text:
        # Only print c if it is not the paragraph delimiter/separator
        if c != PAR_SEP:
            sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
            sys.stdout.flush()

        if c == '.' or c == '!' or c == '?' or c == ';' or c == ':':
            time.sleep(.5)
        elif c == ',':
            time.sleep(.2)
        elif c == PAR_SEP:
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            time.sleep(length)
    print "\n"
```

The only reason that '\r' and '\v' were messing with your cursor position is because your code prints those characters to the screen. Once you add this quick check, it should behave the way you desire.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, and a much easier fix than I thought.

Comment: @Macimoar you're welcome! I know I encountered a similar situation when I was first learning to deal with atypical and non-printable characters, so I'm glad I could help.